# WSL2, access to localhost, but no to 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wsl-2

The connectoion to Apache localhost working well, but not to 127.0.0.1 at all. Need the access to 35729 (livereload) and MySQL ports. Tried a lot of methods

```
ifconfig

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.244.88  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fed5:759c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:d5:75:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2860  bytes 253955 (253.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 936 (936.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 47  bytes 32100 (32.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47  bytes 32100 (32.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Windows firewall turned  off